# create admin front-end for web application?

Tags: php, admin

does one create an admin front-end from scratch for every web application (not CMS sites)?

are there any tools for aiding this process?

some tutorials?

share your thoughts and experiences!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends, if you create a website from scratch without using any CMS, then yes in most cases, you have to create it manually **depending on your site's front-end requirements**.

However, if you are creating your site with a CMS such as Joomla, etc, then admin site comes with them and you don't need to create yourself in this case.

And yes, it would be great to see if somebody comes up with such tool to create admins for your custom site.

Comment: yes i was focusing on web applications and not CMS sites. have u used CodeIgniter's Expression Engine? i thought maybe it could aid me somehow on the front-end but im not sure how.

Comment: @fayer: well not sure about Expression Engine, i haven't used that.